# Что почитать или посмотреть, чтобы в совершенстве овладеть CMS Drupal и Bitrix?

Tags: php, cms

Подскажите пожалуйста литературу или подкасты, чтобы помимо умения выполнять абсолютно любые задачи на данных cms, ещё и уметь создавать шаблоны, темы, модули и плагины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

мне кажется лучший справочник это 
https://www.drupal.org/developers и https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/

Comment: Да, но хотелось бы русского контента - в виде статей, книг и видео...